# Passing Data between pages from url

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am working on ionic 4 project. My project is getting data json from url using input search . l want passing data when users is click on any items to show them another page for more details . l tried with this code but l get undefined value !

this code is holding search operation

```
export class FlightsearchPage {
  public search = ''
  public flight : any
  filterItems:any;
  callsign : any;
  constructor(private http: HTTP, public loadingController: LoadingController, private nav : NavController) {

    this.addThemFunction
  }

  keyPressed(event: any) { /
    console.log(event.target.value); 
  this.addThemFunction(event.target.value);
  }

 async addThemFunction(search){

  this.http.get('/web/find?query='+search+'', {}, {})
  .then(data => {

    const parsed = JSON.parse(data.data);
    this.flight = parsed.results;
    this.filterItems= this.flight;
    this.callsign = this.flight.detail.flight

    /// here l am try to pass value callsign to page details /// 

    this.nav.navigateForward(`/flightserachdetails/${this.callsign}`)

    }), err=>{
    }
  }


    }
```

details search

```
 <ion-content padding>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Enter your flight number</ion-label>
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="search" (keyup)="keyPressed($event)" placeholder="Ex : iaw556"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of flight"  routerDirection="forward">
      <ion-label>
        <ion-text color="primary">
            <h3 [routerLink]="['/flightserachdetails', id]">{{item.label}}</h3>
          </ion-text>
          <p>{{item.name}}</p>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

</ion-content>
```

this code is getting data from code above

```
export class FlightserachdetailsPage {

  public flight : any
  callsignId = null

  constructor(private http: HTTP, public loadingController: LoadingController, private nav: NavController,private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {


    this.callsignId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')           





}
```

for display data from another page above.

```
<ion-content padding>
   {{callsignId}}
   {{flight.request.fetchBy}}
</ion-content>
```

json response

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "IA107",
      "label": "IA107",
      "detail": {
        "callsign": "IAW107",
        "flight": "IA107", 
       "fetchBy": "IA107"
      },
      "type": "schedule",
    }
  ]
}
```

l am sorry about mess code. any suggestion or give me another code example, please?

Comment: write a service or a method/property in existing service to get the object/item by its id and pass the id of the object/item in url while navigating to the next page and call this service method to get that object by id in the component you are loading on the next page. this is easier I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying and navigating at the same time so remove that from `addThemFunction(search)`.

```
async addThemFunction(search){

    this.http.get('/web/find?query='+search+'', {}, {})
       .then(data => {

          const parsed = JSON.parse(data.data);
          this.flight = parsed.results;
          this.filterItems= this.flight[0];
          this.callsign = this.flight.detail.flight

        }
     }
}
```

You need to remove navigation from `addThemFunction(search)` function and create a new one to navigate when the item is clicked.

```
navigate(id){
    this.nav.navigateForward(`/flightserachdetails/${id}`);
}
```

And remove `routerLink` from h3 and call `navigate()` function when item clicked and pass `id` in that function.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of flight"  routerDirection="forward">
  <ion-label>
    <ion-text color="primary">
        <h3 (click)="navigate(item.id)">{{item.label}}</h3>
      </ion-text>
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

To pass complete object:

```
`this.router.navigate(['flightserachdetails'], item);
```

On next page:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(resp => {
       console.log(resp);
   });
```

Comment: he dosnt working becuase l am using Ionic/Angular 4 so l have to use     `this.nav.navigateForward(`/flightserachdetails/${this.flight.detail.flight}` . it is methods of the Angular router

Comment: I think the issue is that your result is array try `this.filterItems= this.flight[0];`

Comment: when l search for nay query is working fine . but when l click on item l got undefined value in page details

Comment: it is same problem

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: hello sir , there is way to passing multiple value to another page not only one value ? in that cause the url we be hold long values ! right ?

Comment: the problem is l have many values to passing another page . how can l push them in one time without long url . see what l did here . `(click)=navigate(item.flight.identification.number.default,item.flight.airport.origin.position.region.city)` this is one of values l want to push them . l have a lot !

Comment: I have updated the answer you can pass the whole object that you want or that is clicked

Comment: you mean like that `navigate(id){
this.router.navigate(['flightserachdetails'], item);}`

Comment: Yes `navigate(item){ this.router.navigate(['flightserachdetails'], item);}` item instead of id

Comment: l got read line under router . so l did like that  `navigate(item){ 
    this.nav.navigateForward(['flightserachdetails'], item);}` in html `(click)="navigate(item)"` in another page  `this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(resp => {
                  this.callsignId =  resp.item.flight.identification.number.default
              });` . when l click nothing to show ! error in console `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'flightserachdetails'`

Comment: You need to modify your route like this `url/item` where you have defined the route

Comment: l need your help :(