# check network status using network native

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am working on ionic 4 project. My project is getting data `json` from url . l am try to use [Network native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) for ionic to check internet connections for my app .But l got nothing to show. No data and no alert to show  .

```
 constructor(private http: HTTP, public loadingController: LoadingController,private network: Network,
   public alertController : AlertController, public platform : Platform) {


    // watch network for a disconnection
    let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {

      this.AlertNet()

    });

    // stop disconnect watch
    disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();


    // watch network for a connection
    let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('network connected!');


      this.getData()

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
          console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
        }
      }, 3000);
    });

    // stop connect watch
    connectSubscription.unsubscribe();



       }

      async getData() {


          const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
            message: 'Loading'
          });
          await loading.present();
          this.http.get('/v1/airport.json?code=krt', {}, {})
          .then(data => {

            this.test = JSON.parse(data.data);
            const parsed = JSON.parse(data.data);


          }), err=>{
            this.test =err
            loading.dismiss()
          }



      }


     async AlertNet(){

      const alert = await this.alertController.create({
        header: 'Alert',
        subHeader: 'No internet',
        message: 'You do not have an Internet connection. Please check your connection status',
        buttons: [{
          text: "Ok",
          handler: () => { this.platform.backButton.subscribe(()=>{
            navigator['app'].exitApp();
        });
       }
        }]    
        });

      await alert.present();

     }
```

Comment: You linked the documentation, have you followed it? Doesn't seem you are subscribing to the connections anywhere?? Also `it doesn't work` doesn't tell us anything. Do you get an error message or something?

Comment: there is nothing to show ! . maybe l am wrote the code in wrong way ! . do you have alternative ?

Comment: Well did you do it like the documentation says? I don't know what you expect `this.network.onConnect` and `this.network.onDisconnect` is supposed to do?

Comment: l follow the doc . l got a lot of errors

Comment: Well this code you are showing isn't at all what the documentation said. So what error do you get if you do it like in the documentation? :)

Comment: I also think that one issue is perhaps that this is called before platform is ready, so you should wrap everything inside `this.platform.ready().then(.. do stuff ..)`

Comment: give my few min

Comment: @AJT_82 check my update

Comment: Now the code looks better. Isn't the error pretty self explanatory? ;) Have you tried moving the async code to it's own (async) function? That should solve it.

Comment: l am so sorry . l am beginner in programming . how can l move async code to it's own (async) function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally l found it the problem . Several failed attempts have reached a conclusion :

```
constructor(private http: HTTP, public loadingController: LoadingController,public network: Network,

   public alertController : AlertController, public toastController : ToastController) {


    if (this.network.type == 'none'){
      this.AlertNet()


    }else if(this.network.type === 'wifi'){

      this.getData()
    }

    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(()=> {
      if(network.Connection.WIFI){

        this.presentToastWithOptions()

      }
    });

    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(()=> {
      this.presentToast()
    });

   }
   async presentToast() {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: 'You dont have internet connection :(',
      duration: 2000
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  async presentToastWithOptions() {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: 'Internet connection is back :)',
      showCloseButton: true,
      position: 'top',
      closeButtonText: 'Done'
    });
    toast.present();
  }

 async AlertNet(){

  const alert = await this.alertController.create({
    header: 'Alert',
    subHeader: 'No internet',
    message: 'You do not have an Internet connection. Please check your connection status',
    buttons: [{
      text: "Ok"


    }]    
    });

  await alert.present();

 }
```

If you use `onConnect` and `onDisconnect` they are only  working for detected connection  . example if you are inside app and you switch off wifi `onDisconnect` he will work to detected that and `onConnect` same work if you switch on wifi or Mobile data .

if you want to detected your connection for first run for your app you can do with `network.type`

```
   if (this.network.type == 'none'){
      this.AlertNet()


    }else if(this.network.type === 'wifi'){

      this.getData()
    }
```

when l used this code above and run app he is start to check my phone if he has internet connection or net . if he doesn't  has he will show me alert immediately .

Comment: I wrote this in my answer as well, that if you **initially** want to check the connection, use `this.network.type !== 'none'` (connection exists) ;)

Comment: do you have any idea about this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592495/passing-data-between-pages-from-url/54592676?noredirect=1#comment96013812_54592676

Comment: best answer , works fine for me on ionic5. Great solution

Answer (score 2):

Move your alert controller code to its own async function, since you cannot use `await` without `async`, as you have already established. Also I would suggest to place the connection code inside `platform.ready` so that we know for sure it has loaded:

```ts
constructor(private platform: Platform, private network: Network ......) {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      this.openAlert();
    });

  // watch network for a connection
  let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('network connected!');
    // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
    // before we determine the connection type. Might need to wait.
    // prior to doing any api requests as well.
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
        console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
        this.getData();
      }
    }, 3000);
  });
  });
}

async openAlert() {
  const alert = await this.alertController.create({
    header: 'Alert',
    subHeader: 'No internet',
    message: 'You do not have an Internet connection.'
    buttons: [{
      text: "Ok",
      handler: () => { 
        // you are propbably going to run into issues here...
        this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
          navigator['app'].exitApp();
        });
       }
      }]    
    });
  await alert.present();
}
```

This seems to work just fine when testing, starting app when having connection on, then switching it off, and back on.

[image]

If you want, when coming into component, check that there is a connection, then do a check for `this.network.type !== 'none'` (connection exists)

Comment: `[ts] Cannot find name 'openAlert'. [2304]`

Comment: Well have you added the function `openAlert` to your code? Where have you placed it?

Comment: my god , its nothing to show . even not data to show

Comment: edited answer to make it as clear as possible... should work. If not, post error message.

Comment: You are also instantly unsubscribing to the network connection watch, why? You should unsubscribe when component is destroyed.

Comment: l also removed unsubscribing for both . its same

Comment: I don't know, works fine for me when I started app with network on, then switched it off (shows console of disconnected) and then switched back on (shows rest of console logs)... attached an image as well in answer.

Comment: anyway . thank you very much for tried to help me. l cant see any console because native plugin required real device

Comment: @pabloescobar My image is console log from device. Chrome has in developer tools `remote devices` where you can see the console logs from device. If this didn't solve your issue, I see only that you create a repo, which I can clone and test.

Comment: do you know ? , l did a lot of test from different codes and even your code l found the problem is with code native is not working with me !

Comment: Could you create a repo and share it with me, I can take a look.

Comment: l hate repo , l dont know how is work ! . l can give you access code for anydesk

Comment: Well that is of course an error, cordova isn't available, you need to run on device.

Comment: so that what l mean . l cant see console

Comment: As I said above, Chrome has in developer tools **remote devices** where you can see console logs **from devices**! That is where my image is from. I am running on device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188139/discussion-between-pabloescobar-and-ajt-82).

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to chat. Please create a repo I can clone and test. Otherwise try to create a brand new project and just try if you can get the network to work. Sometimes it's just best to start with minimal project and slowly add code to be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: sorry for that . l found the problem where is it . l just explain  to you there . no need for chat . thanks

Comment: So did my answer help? :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use plugins for network checking, I got a very very and very easy way to check if the user has Internet connection or not, so all we have to do is that to use this:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
   console.log('Internet is connected');
} else {
   console.log('No internet connection');
}
```

At here navigator is not a variable created by me. The navigator. onLine property provides a boolean value whether or not the user is connected to the Internet. … Browser and real device also supports online and offline events whenever the browser is goes offline or comes online.

This is the very easy and working way, I’m sure it will help.